# Type mismatch error in excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am getting an error as type mismatch on last line.

If I put the number eg: 2080 in place of rowcount in formula, it works fine.

```
Dim count as integer
Dim rowcount as integer
Set rngData = ws1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
rowCount = rngData.Rows.count

count = ws1.Evaluate("=SUM(IFERROR(1/COUNTIF(L2:L & rowCount, L2:L & rowCount,0))")
```

Comment: have you tested my code in my answer below ? any feedback ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to seperate the Text and constant past of your Formula, with the variables part. You do that by splitting it with `" & RowCount & "`.

**Note**: you would be better to declare `Dim rowcount as Long` , also `Dim count as Long`.

If your formula worked with your code when instead of `RowCount` you had `2080`, then change your formula to:

```
ws1.Evaluate("=SUM(IFERROR(1/COUNTIF(L2:L" & RowCount & ", L2:L" & RowCount & "),0))")
```

Comment: There's a missing bracket there: `ws1.Evaluate("=SUM(IFERROR(1/COUNTIF(L2:L" & RowCount & ", L2:L" & RowCount & "),0))")`

Comment: You've changed the formula. COUNTIF is checking for unique instances, so it should have the same range as criteria too.